# Create a unique raster from a grid_terrain function from LASCatalog files

Tags: lidr

When you use grid_terrain function in lidR with a catalog, the result is a virtual raster mosaic is returned (see gdalbuildvrt). But when i clic on (gdalbuildvrt) in pdf vignette, nothing is under the clic.
How can i create a unique raster of this virtual result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is: *how to merge a virtual raster mosaic into a single file?* I suggest you to ask another question with better tags because the question is not related to `lidR`. I'm going to anwer to the question: *how to create a single raster instead of a virtual mosiac with `lidR` ?*

When you use a function `grid_*` (terrain, canopy, density and so on) the output is a `RasterLayer`. When processing a `LAScatalog` you have access to all the feature of the processing engine including writing each chunk into a file on disk.

```
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "path/to/templated/filename_{ID}"
```

In the case of `grid_*` function several raster files are written on disk. By default the paths to the files are returned. But with rasters we can do something more clever and return an virtual raster mosaic instead of a list of path using `gdalbuildvrt` from `gdalUtils`.

This append only if you use a templated path to write the outputs. If you let it empty the regular behaviour returns a `RasterLayer` in memory.

```
opt_output_files(ctg) <- ""
```

Then you can write it into a file with `raster::writeRaster`.

Also you can't click on `gdalbuildvrt` in the pdf doc. It is a link to the documentation of a function from the package `gdalUtils`. Use the doc in R with `?grid_terrain`

Notice that you can disable the virtual raster mosaic option with `options(lidR.buildVRT = FALSE)`

Comment: thank you for this response, it's ok.

Comment: how can i do to answered the questions ?

Comment: i have found the acceptance answer with the V in green near the answer !

Comment: That's it!! Please do it every time an answer satisfies you in the future.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help and your reactivity !